# How to override label using EditorTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

For a `string` property in MVC3, I've created a partial view at `~/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml` and I've placed within it the following:

```
@model System.String
<div class="Input">
    @Html.TextBox("", this.Model)
    @Html.ValidationMessage("")
</div>
```

Viewing the result, it looks good. But the label is still showing up. As you can see it's not included in the partial view, above, so it must be coming from the base view.

How do I override the label output so when I do `@Html.EditorForModel()`, my `string` properties will have a customized label?

Comment: I ended up creating a custom `Object.cshtml` template. But I'd still like to know if there is a way to just override the label portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom `Object.cshtml` template.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.ComponentModel.DisplayName` attribute to override the member name.

For example:

```
public string MyProperty {get;set;}  //displays "MyProperty"

[DisplayName("My Property")] 
public string MyProperty {get;set;}  //displays "My Property"
```